# Copying Array Content to Another Array in Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, cpu-registers

I'm looking to copy some elements of an array to another one in Assembly. Both arrays are accessed via pointers which are stored in registers. So, edx would be pointing to one array and eax would point to another. Basically, edx points to an array of character read in from a text file, and I'd like eax to contain only 32 of the characters. Here's what I'm attempting to do:

I386 Assembly using NASM

```
add edx, 8 ; the first 8 characters of the string are not wanted

mov cl, 32
ip_address:
; move the character currently pointed to by edx to eax (mov [eax], [edx])
inc edx
inc eax
loop ip_address
```

Again, i'd like this to place the 32 characters after the first eight to be placed in the second array. The problem is that I'm stumped on how to do this.. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do direct memory-to-memory moves in x86.  You need to use another scratch register:

```
mov ecx, [edx]
mov [eax], ecx
```

Or something like that...

Comment: You get a segfault when you use `ecx` because it overwrites your loop counter (`cl` is the low 8 bits of `ecx`).  You need to use a different register for the copy: `ebx` seems the logical choice.

Comment: @Stephen Canon
Actually, I was using ebx. The seg fault was due to mov cl, 32 being commented out.

Comment: Actually, you *can* do "direct memory-to-memory moves in x86".

Comment: @DigitalRoss: You mean in a modern intel processor? and How?

Comment: @TheMask, he's referring to the string copy instructions.  See his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Both ia32 and ia64 *do* contain a memory-to-memory string move instruction that can move bytes, "words", and "doublewords".

```
movsb
movsw
movsd
```

The source address is specified in ESI and the destination in EDI.<sup>1</sup> By itself, it moves one byte, word, or doubleword. If the **rep** prefix is used, then ECX will contain a count and the instruction will move an entire string of values.

---

<sup>1. I think these instructions are the *reason* that the ESI and EDI registers are so named. (Source Index and Destination Index.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to just do:

```
mov  ebx, [edx]
mov [eax], ebx
```

Be aware that under many platform's ABIs, `ebx` is a callee-save register, so you will need to save and restore its value in your function.

The *simpler* solution is to link against the standard library and call `memcpy`, which is perfectly acceptable in assembly, and will usually be substantially faster than writing your own loop.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. I'll have to remember that if I ever need an alternative to the above.

Comment: Or you could use `rep movs` to copy from `[esi]` to `[edi]`.

Comment: @ninjalj: you could, but calling memcpy will be substantially faster on at least some architectures.